# how to Create some nodes of a content type when created a node of another content type?

Tags: nodes

I would like to create an editable task table with slickgrid view, where each row is a node (of content type 2) that will be created automatically by a different content type (the 1st content type) or a webform.

Content type 1 - The 1st content type have 4 fields (this node will create automatically some nodes of the second content type)

1st - "Days" - is a Date field type - with unlimited (1 to 10) values

2nd - "City's" - is a Reference to a Term - with unlimited (1 to 10) values

3th - "Type of operation" is a Reference to a Term - with an unique value

4th - "Number of person by city" is a Integer field type - with an unique value

Content type 2 - the 2nd content type have those fields

1st - "Day" - is a Date field type - with an unique value

2nd - "City" - is a Reference to a Term - with an unique value

3th - "Type of operation" is a Reference to a Term - with an unique value

4th - "Name of a person" is a text field - with an unique value

Now for example if i create a node of Content type 1 with 5 values for the date field and 5 for the City's and the number "2" for the integer field, it will create automatically **5*5*2= 50** nodes of Content type 2, the "name of a person" field will be created empty of course.

I think i must create a module or perhaps with rules it's possible ? is it possible to replace the content type 1 by a webform? I'm newbie in drupal module developement. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Custom module is the best way to go. With rules it's really complex. You need to use below hook in your custom module to solve above problem.

- [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) to hook into above node creation. Hook Responds to creation of a new node.
- In above hook implementation you need to create new nodes using code. Please find [article](http://www.lightrains.com/blog/programmatically-create-node-drupal-7) which explains same.